# SQL Server: How to select existing IDs and insert them to the new ID field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `Category` and `Movie` and I have a mapping table `MovieCategory` (a movie can have one or multiple categories).

I then noticed that in my table `Movie`, there's not one movie with multiple categories.

So I want to delete the `MovieCategory` mapping table. But first, to accomplish this, I created a new column `IDCategory` in my table `Movie` which references the `Category`  (a movie can now have only one single category).

And now, my new `IDCategory` column is null for all my `Movie` entries, I want to select all the existing `Category` entries in my mapping table `MovieCategory` and then insert the selected `IDCategory` to my new `IDCategory` column in the `Movie` table.

How can I accomplish this?

Here are my columns:

```
MovieCategory 
---------------------
IDMovie    IDCategory
----------------------
```

`Category` table has `IDCategory` and `Movie` table has `IDMovie` and the new `IDCategory` column

Comment: I don't think you have _Fields_ there, you have _Columns_ instead, BTW I read your question but I can't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Sami Sorry my brother Sami, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE M
SET IDCategory = MC.IDCategory
FROM Movie M
     JOIN MovieCategory MC ON MC.IDMovie = M.ID;
```

This is one of the basics of SQL; I suggest having a read up on the `UPDATE` syntax: [SQL Update Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) & [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Larnu _Please not **w3schools**_

Comment: @sami please spell my name correctly. :) And W3CSchools is *fine* for an introduction; which is what the OP appears to need.

Comment: See? I edit it, and here is a [link to why not w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: @Larnu. . . You should use some other short name nearest `Larnu`.

Comment: nearest Larnu @YogeshSharma ?

Comment: @Larnu. . . i.e. (`Yogesh Sharma - sharma`).

Comment: @Sami that accepted answer does state *"There's no issue with linking to information you believe (or, better, know) to be accurate, but as others have noted, consider linking to official documentation instead."* I've done both here.

Comment: You mean abbreviate it @YogeshSharma ? I'm not sure you really can abbreviate it (although i have had some shorten it to "Larn" when pronoucing it. (it's an extra letter -_- ))